# Combinatorics with 3 equations

Tags: combinatorics, diophantine-equations

Ok, so I want for all combinations of positive integers (a,b,c) for the Equations

$$-10(c-2ab)+\frac{b-5}{a}=52$$
$$a-b+c=53$$
$$a(b+7)=54$$

the product abc

So I want the product abc not the solutions for the euquation
aargh, I feel so stupid for not being able to solve this. They are just equations :(

I tried just solving for one variable and then plugging in, but it didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $54 = 2\cdot3^3$, we have that $b+7$ may only be $9, 18, 27$ or $54$. Then use the fact that $a$ divides $b-5$.

Comment: $a=3, b = 11, c = 61$

Answer (score 0):

The equations even over the complex numbers give either $a=3$ or $65a^2 - 89a + 9=0$.
Of course, over the integers $a=3, b=11, c=61$. Substituting $b=54/a-7$, we obtain
$c=-(a^2  - 46a - 54)/a$ from the second equation, and then $(a-3)(65a^2-89a+9)=0$ form the first equation.

Comment: thx, but how did you solve it?

Comment: Just by substituting $b$ and $c$. We know that $a\neq 0$ by the third equation.

Comment: thx heaps for that